# Solr Dynamic Fields with Custom field type not working properly

Tags: solr

I have added a wild card dynamic field in my schema.xml

```
    <dynamicField name="test_srch_*" type="filter_text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    
<!-- Tokenized text for search -->
    <fieldType name="filter_text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

The output in solr is not being lowercased and also individual token searches like BBB bbb CCC ccc are not working. It is only working with "BBB, CCC"

```
<arr name="test_srch_2">
<str>BBB, CCC</str>
</arr>
```

Can someone please suggest as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: _Output_ doesn't change based on the analysis chain. The chain only affects which tokens are generated when indexing and when querying. Did you reindex after changing the type? Do you have any examples of queries that doesn't work? What does the Analysis page show for the field?

Comment: Can you share the query that you are making ? Also did you reindex the data after you made changes to "filter_text" field ?

Comment: Yes, full indexing has been done after the changes were made. I am making the query at the SKU level in which one of these fields is mapped. Somehow Analysis is not working (not sure if it was licensed or bought)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to restart the servers. My bad!! Any changes to schema.xml require a server restart for the changes to be available as part of the core. Case insensitive search is working fine now

Comment: It requires a core reload - you do not have to restart Solr itself.